# Cube does not perfectly fit in square camera in orthographic view

Tags: rendering, blender, isometric

[image: Cube improperly fitted into camera frame]

[image: Using align view gives this result, which is still not properly fitted into the camera frame]

I am trying to render a cube in this isometric view, but with a square camera it does not want to fit completely. There is either free space or I would have to not render a chunk. How would I make it fit? I have put the rotation of the camera correctly for an isometric view.